# Implementing a Custom Identity and IPrincipal in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iprincipal, iidentity

I have a basic MVC 2 beta app where I am trying to implement a custom Identity and Principal classes.

I have created my classes that implement the IIdentity and IPrincipal interfaces, instantiated them and then assigned the CustomPrincipal object to my Context.User in Application_AuthenticateRequest of the Global.asax.

This all succeeds and the objects look good.  When I begin to render the Views the pages are now failing.  The first failure is in the default LogoOnUserControl view on the following line of code:

```
 [ <%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %> ]
```

If I pull this out it then fails on a different "Html.ActionLink" line of code.

The error I receive is:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'
>   occurred in WebDev.WebHost40.dll but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Type is not
>   resolved for member
>   'Model.Entities.UserIdentity,Model,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Is there some additional properties that I need to implement in my Identity in order to use a custom Identity in MVC?  I tried to implement [Serializable()]  in the Identity class but it didn't seem to have an impact.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried 3-4 alternate ways of implemented this but still fails with the same error.  If I use GenericIdentity/GenericPrincipal classes directly it does not error.

```
GenericIdentity ident = new GenericIdentity("jzxcvcx");
GenericPrincipal princ = new GenericPrincipal(ident, null);
Context.User = princ;
```

But this gets me nowhere since I am trying to use the CustomIdentity to hold a couple of properties.  If I implement the IIdentity/IPrincipal interfaces or inherit GenericIdentity/GenericPrincipal for my CustomIdentity/CustomPrincipal it fails with the original error above.

Comment: Re: the up vote...Are you also seeing a similar issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured this one out with a little help from the web :)  The trick is that you have to implement the ISerializable interface in your class that implements IIdentity.  I hope this helps save someone else some time :)

**Class declaration:**

```
[Serializable]
    public class ForumUserIdentity : IIdentity, ISerializable
```

**Implementation for ISerializable:**

```
#region ISerializable Members

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            if (context.State == StreamingContextStates.CrossAppDomain)
            {
                GenericIdentity gIdent = new GenericIdentity(this.Name, this.AuthenticationType);
                info.SetType(gIdent.GetType());

                System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] serializableMembers;
                object[] serializableValues;

                serializableMembers = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(gIdent.GetType());
                serializableValues = FormatterServices.GetObjectData(gIdent, serializableMembers);

                for (int i = 0; i < serializableMembers.Length; i++)
                {
                    info.AddValue(serializableMembers[i].Name, serializableValues[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Serialization not supported");
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Here is the [link to the article that has more detail on the "Feature"](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CommentView,guid,cfcaf6c4-63cf-4cf1-8361-ed3db07496a4.aspx)

Comment: this feature is bs... its been around since 2006 and still affecting me with my asp.net **mvc-3** application.

Comment: This solved my problem. The same thing goes for IPrincipal as well.

Comment: why are you created a new `GenericIdentity` instead of a `CustomIdentity` in your DeSerialization code? => `GenericIdentity gIdent = new GenericIdentity(...)' ??

Comment: Just wanted to note that there is a difference between `System.ISerializable` and `System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable`.  I struggled with the first for a while before realizing the second (**System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable**) was the one I needed.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. I solved it by moving my principal creating from MvcApplication_AuthenticateRequest to MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest.
I dunno why/how, but it solved the problem :)

```
        void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string encTicket = authCookie.Value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);
                BiamedIdentity id = new BiamedIdentity(ticket);
                GenericPrincipal prin = new GenericPrincipal(id, null);
                HttpContext.Current.User = prin;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

With me it seems to work when I inherit my Identity class from `MarshalByRefObject`.

Also note: when using Linq-to-Sql there was no problem. I switched to Entity-Framework and bang, I got the above message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503380/how-expensive-is-using-marshalbyrefobject-compared-to-serialization there is more on marshalbyrefobject