# StreamWriter overwriting previous records?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, xml-serialization, streamwriter

Hi I am wondering how I can keep the previous records with my stream writer, if I use the below code it works fine when the student record is created but when I create a second student record the previous record is gone? How can I keep all records?

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
        TextWriter w = new StreamWriter("c:\\list.xml");
        s.Serialize(w, student);
        w.Close();
    }
```

**EDIT UPDATE:**

From the partial answer below I keep getting this error `Type WcfServiceLibrary1.Student' in Assembly 'WcfServiceLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not marked as serializable`

I have decorated the Student Class with  `[Serializable()]` so im not sure whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) overload of StreamWriter's constructor to append new data instead of overwriting.

```
TextWriter w = new StreamWriter("c:\\list.xml", true);
```

**Update**:
I see, it works only with BinaryFormatter and not with XmlSerializer, because second write makes XML invalid. Unless you need XML format for some reason, using binary format is easier. This should work:

```
   static void WriteStudent(Student S)
    {
        BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream w = new FileStream("c:\\list.dat", FileMode.Append))
        {
            f.Serialize(w, S);
        }
    }

    static List<Student> ReadStudents()
    {
        BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (Stream w = new FileStream("c:\\list.dat", FileMode.Open))
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            while (w.Position < w.Length)
            {
                students.Add((Student)f.Deserialize(w));
            }
            return students;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt work. Same issue but instead of my way your way ontop of not appending also loses the xml format in the xml doc on the second run.

Comment: WriteStudent throws an exception:  `Type 'WcfServiceLibrary1.Student' in Assembly 'WcfServiceLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.`

Comment: @JungleBoogie: This means that you must decorate Student class with [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: `[Serializable()]
    public class Student` if I try this I still get the error?

Comment: I have updated my question hopefully we can finish this question off.

Comment: @JungleBoogie: And is the error exactly the same, including "WcfServiceLibrary1.Student"? If so, then I ran out of ideas. I tested it on my computer and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah exact same, I wonder if it could be my hashed password and salt fields? See my updated question.

Comment: I didnt use the rest of the code because it doesnt fit with my web service but it should still work?

Comment: Even with Student class declared as above in your question (including Password ans Salt), program still works fine on my computer. Is your Student class in the same assembly as method AddStudent? If it is not, then verify that you reference up-to-date version of assembly with Student class (I saw many times that badly set reference to assembly in Visual Studio caused old version of assembly to overwrote the current version)

Comment: Nah it is in the same program, really not sure whats going on?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611756/how-to-debug-exception-type-is-not-marked-as-serializable-when-the-type-is-m) might solve this problem.

Comment: Nuf I got it to work, for some reason I had to put serilizable on every datacontract class (even the ones not used) not sure why tho. I have a problem tho how do I read the .dat file in a datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is opening a file, discard the existing content, serialize a single `student` object of type `Student` into XML, write the XML into a file and close it.

What you have to do is almost exactly the same, except that you have to serialize a list of students rather than a single one. For that purpose, try doing this:

```
s.Serialize(w, students);
```

instead of this:

```
s.Serialize(w, student);
```

And don't forget to change `typeof(Student)` to the typeof of whatever class you are using to maintain a list (that will be a type of `students` object).

Comment: Hi Vlad using students (which funnyily enough is what my list<Student> is named, returns an error. There was an error generating the XML document... yeah thanks Visual studio very informative!

Comment: you are correct in what you say that I am discarding the existing content, but I also want to serialize a single student because this is a wcf rest and only one student will be created at a time so all I want to do is "append" the next created student collection.

Comment: @JungleBoogie: Then use Nuf's answer :) I mean, really, what else can you do? Parse the whole file back, add a student into a parsed list, then serialize it again...

Answer (score 0):

It won't work the way you expecting to. `StreamWriter` will not do any magic to insert your new `Student` record inside the root element. You need to deserialize the list from file, add new entry and serialize it back. Alternatively you can keep the list of students in memory, add new record to it and then serialize the entire set.

Neither of those are particularly great ways to store incremental updates. You should look into using SQL Server (or express) instead.